# How can I use createbrowserRouter outside of React tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The React Router docs state:

> Due to the decoupling of fetching and rendering in the design of the data APIs, you should create your router outside of the React tree with a statically defined set of routes. For more information on this design, please see the Remixing React Router blog post and the When to Fetch conference talk.

I'm a bit confused how to create my router outside of my React tree when I need my routes wrapped in an authentication component.

Currently I have a main.tsx:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <GenReMsal>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </GenReMsal>
)
```

`GenReMsal` is an implementation of `@azure/msal-react`

Inside my App.tsx I have my router wrapped in authentication components which also come from `@azure/msal-react`

```
function App({ msalContext }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <Router currentUser={msalContext.accounts[0]} />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <GenReLogin />
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </>
  )
}

export default withMsal(App)
```

My router component is where I am calling `createBrowserRouter`:

```
function Router({ currentUser }: Props) {
  const userInfo = { name: currentUser.name }

  function defaulNewAPIs() {
    getReasonTypes()
    return 'data'
  }

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/:appTypeId?',
      element: <AppLayout currentUser={userInfo} />,
      loader: defaulNewAPIs,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ])

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}

export default Router
```

Now I am not sure how to call `createBrowserRouter` outside the React tree when I need it to be wrapped by that authentication component.